# how to get the URL from mainActivity to the second activity using intents?

Tags: android, url, android-intent, android-activity, webview

How to pass URL from one activity to another activity?

I also had a look for passing data from one activity to another activity, I'm facing the problem. When I run the program it's passing to second activity but page is blank.

Activity1 code

```java
String url = result[1].toLowerCase();
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), choice.class);
i.putExtra("url", url);
startActivity(i);
break;
```

Second activity:

```java
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
  String url = extras.getString("url");
  Toast t7 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Visiting: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  t7.show();
  WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
  Toast t9 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "loading:" + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  t9.show();
  view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  view.loadUrl(url);
  Toast t8 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "loaded:" + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  t8.show();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: blind guess: you forgot about internet permission (as this code should work) ... now reputation's farmers make this an answer ...

Comment: hi Nick, yep i have added the internet permissions too.. I have added the Toast and its displaying as www.google.com is loaded but page is blank.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, InitializationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("isOPenImeiDialog", true);
            intent.putExtra("serverMsg", result);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: hi  suman, still its not working.. i'm getting a toast message as url loaded but its blank. kindly please help me.

Comment: hello, thanku all.. webpage is displayed successfully. it was a minor mistake.